# How to build jQuery specially for some kind of browser?

Tags: jquery

I had this question because that I want to minimize footprint of my distribution as my distribution is targeted for Chrome only.

So is it possible to build jQuery specially for some kind of browser only to make it smaller?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it smaller"? Do you mean the size of the code you're trying to write?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Chrome only build of jQuery. But you can use [jQuery 3](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/). With this version they dropped support for many old browsers completly, wich makes the new version mutch smaller.

Since 3.1.0 of jQuery there is even a [`slim build`](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/07/07/jquery-3-1-0-released-no-more-silent-errors/). This version has no support for AJAX, effects and deprecated code. If you don't need these, you can use that version too.

[jQuery 3.0.0 Release](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)
[jQuery 3.1.0 Relese](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/07/07/jquery-3-1-0-released-no-more-silent-errors/)